# How to do a Flutter Firebase app for both Mobile and Desktop at the same time

Tags: windows, flutter, firebase, mobile, desktop

I see many samples and videos on how to do firebase for mobile and they call this "multiplatform".  However, I don't see much on the desktop.  There is one video on [firebase flutter Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tw7L2NkhwPc) by using a web and it seems to work.  However, I do not see any tutorials for both mobile and desktop.  Firebase would be a great example on syncing between desktop and mobile.  We have such an app in development right now.  Desktop development is new, but I'm surprised how little there is.

There is a library called firebase_dart, but the documentation seems weak.

Comment: As far as I know firebase with flutter windows/desktop has limited to no access. I might be wrong. meanwhile you can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743910/flutterhow-can-we-use-firebase-database-with-desktop-application

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!

https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Answer (score 2):

The package [firedart](https://pub.dev/packages/firedart) with the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tw7L2NkhwPc) listed above works in both desktop (linux and android without much modification..
What needed to be modified?

- I had difficulty with the button on the very top of the phone, so I
  added a sized box.
- I had difficulty with debugPrint or print so I
  added a Text widget with the results (to string).

That also worked.
Although I would like to not use fluent_ui, it does work for both desktop and mobile.  I'm not sure what to do with realtime db, but I think I can make the firedart work for user sync between mobile and desktop.

It would be better if I could get [firebase_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dart) to work.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tw7L2NkhwPc

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!
https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte

Comment: Did you get authentication to work? I installed `firedart` and added the appId and apiKey but still cannot get this to work.

Comment: Yes works fine.  Make sure you are using firestore and not fire dart   you can look at the code on tipitaka Pali reader I have a secret env file I use .  You can look in main.  Bksubhuti is my GitHub.  Right now only logging in .  Later my friend will do sync.  When I do only firedart it works fine. But we  are mixing sql local db and firedart.